# Servlet exception mapping

Tags: java, jsp, exception, servlets

I want to display a specific jsp when an Exception occurs. I have a custom exception.
I have already mapped it in the web.xml

```
  <error-page>
    <location>/WebContents/A3/jsp/test.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

This is my custom exception

```
public class TestFileListException extends ServletException
```

And this is what is in my servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        throw new TestFileListException("werw");
}
```

Please help me point out what is wrong in my flow/logic.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/WebContents/A3/jsp/test.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```